# React NavLink: margins added to a tag inside are not clickable

Tags: css, reactjs

I've added margins to .NavItem a and clicking on margin area does not trigger the link. It triggers only by clicking in the content itself in the middle. By inspecting the element, styles added to  tag link and suppose to work.

```
.NavItem a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: .75rem .5rem;
    color: rgb(var(--backClr));
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 1.4rem;
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Margins exist *outside* the element. Try padding instead.

Comment: That worked, thanks